# How to handle cancel when UI allows new objects

Tags: ios, core-data, magicalrecord

Pretty standard iOS app in which a view allows users to create new entities.  In my case the view is associated with one parent entity and N potential children.

Currently when the UI launches a new entity is created in the default (main thread) MOC.  If the user adds children they are also thrown into that MOC.  After all the if the user decides to hit cancel I have to go through that MOC and delete the parent and all the children.

Even worse is the case in which they edit an existing entity.  If they make changes I then have to try and change the entity back.

I think there is a better way, but I am not sure if this is ok to do.

Using MagicalRecord I can create a new MOC (background) that would be used to create/edit the entity for the view.  In the case of save I could save the MOC, in the case of cancel I could just throw away the MOC.

My main concern is the creating a new MOC in MagicalRecord:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
```

does create the MOC on the background thread.  Is this an issue when using that MOC in conjunction with the UI which is running on the main thread?

EDIT:

Andy is correct that is the right way.  Just in case anyone is wondering the way to do this in MagicalRecord is:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *tempContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_newMainQueueContext];
tempContext.parentContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact scenario I use child contexts for (not, as is quite popular, for asynchronous data import, which I find they tend to be a terrible choice for if you need to do any merging of client and server data whatsoever, and have to go through the main thread to save anyway).

You simply create a new main queue context with no persistent store coordinator, set its `parentContext` property to your main context, and then work with it as you would any other context. If the user presses cancel, do nothing - just let that context die, and the objects will die with it. If the user presses save, simply save the context, and the changes will be pushed up to your main context.

I'm not familiar enough with MagicalRecord to say whether there's a convenience method of some kind to create the appropriate context, but it's straightforward enough to do without one.

Comment: Perfect thanks!  I updated the question to show how to do that within MagicalRecord.